# React: Render components that are properties of an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

To build a navigation menu I want to sender a set of `MenuItemComponent`s that have label and icon
I want to import those icons from an external library and then pass them as a propery of an object (that come from external library).
This is the interface for that item

```
export interface MenuItem {
  id: number
  name: string
  icon?: ReactNode,
  path: string,
}
```

On the page I want to map this array with labels and icons.

```
{
   headerMenuItems.map((item: MenuItem) => (
     <MenuItemComponent item={item}/>
   ))
}
```

And here's my `<MenuItemComponent />`

```
import React from "react"
import { MenuItem } from "./items"


export interface MenuItemProps {
  item: MenuItem
}

export const MenuItemComponent = ({item}: MenuItemProps) => {
  const Icon = () => <>{item.icon}</>

  return (
    <a href={item.path}>
      <div>
        <Icon />
        <div>{item.name}</div>
      </div>
    </a>
  )
}
```

But I'm getting an error

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
>       in Icon (at MenuItem.tsx:14)

How can I get the desired result?

And a link to CodeSandbox
[image: Edit frosty-curie-fblm8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid values for `MenuItem`. `icon` is component not node.

You could change it like this [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-swartz-tvcj9)

```
export interface MenuItem {
  id: number
  name: string
  icon?: React.FC,
  path: string,
}
```

And then

```
export const MenuItemComponent = ({ item }: MenuItemProps) => {
  const { icon: Icon } = item;

  return (
    <a href={item.path}>
      <div>
        {Icon && <Icon />}
        <div>{item.name}</div>
      </div>
    </a>
  );
};
```